# Github page version number syntax

Tags: github, github-pages, versioning

I have a github repo that is also a github page. I use it as a CDN like so:

https://agentscript.org/src/Model.js

(agentscript.org is a CNAME forwarder to backspaces.github.io/agentscript/)

I would like to access the code by release number. So for example something like:

https://agentscript.org@0.9.0/src/Model.js

Is there a way for me to do this? The above fails. Maybe a different syntax?

Note that npm publishing allows this to work on npm based CDNs like skypack or unpkg:

https://unpkg.com/agentscript@0.9.0/src/Model.js
https://cdn.skypack.dev/agentscript@0.9.0/src/Model.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages doesn't offer a feature like this.  The reason is that GitHub Pages is designed to host a personal website or a site for your open source project, but isn't designed to be a CDN.  [The documentation outlines that there are limits](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#guidelines-for-using-github-pages), so if you need a CDN, you need to host your project on an actual CDN.